# THREE.EffectComposer in A-Frame

Tags: three.js, aframe

Anyone has a good example on how to use THREE.EffectComposer correctly in A-Frame? Especially the combination of EffectComposer and PMRemGenerator.

Used https://gist.github.com/donmccurdy/31560945d5723737e6c656a2974ab628 for now, but this method breaks a couple of things. The inspector, but more importantly the use of PMRemGenerator for example. (It also doesn't work in VR, but that's minor for my specific project)

And https://github.com/wizgrav/aframe-effects doesn't work on recent versions anymore, and doesn't seem to be maintained anymore. (And I'm too much of a newbie to try and fix that I'm afraid) (edited)

UPDATE: Edited the original question to make it clear the combination PMRemGenerator / EffectComposer is the important part. VR not so much, but that wasn't clear in the original form.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. VR post-processing depends on on-going THREE work that you can follow on this PR: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15840

Comment: And forgetting the VR part, but making it work together with PMRemGenerator, would that be possible?

Comment: No idea. It looks like it's worth a separate question.

Comment: Well, that was a bit the goal of the question. Apparently not clear enough  I updated the question.